firebase init genkit unsupported
I am following the Genkit with Firebase Cloud Functions tutorial and I'm getting the following error when running firebase init genkit:

genkit is not a supported feature; must be one of database, firestore, functions, hosting, hosting:github, storage, emulators, remoteconfig, extensions, frameworks.

I opened an issue here: https://github.com/firebase/genkit/issues/180

Have you made sure your Firebase CLI is up-to-date? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#update-cli

Yes, Firebase CLI and node are up to date. I think the docs are wrong because I can't find any other documentation about firebase init genkit.

You have to upgrade the firebase-tools package to the latest version which is 13.9.0.
To check the current version run: firebase --version
Run: npm i -g firebase-tools to upgrade.

Yup, this was it. I had a second installation of firebase mucking things up. I removed that and updated and all is good. Thanks!

I was able to get this working but not by following the docs (they seem wrong).
Steps

Create a new project folder
Run firebase init functions (I think this is where the typo is in the docs)
cd into the functions folder
Run genkit init and select Firebase as "Deployment Platform"
In package.json, set the firebase-admin version to 12.1.0

"firebase-admin": "12.1.0",

Finally, run firebase deploy --only functions

